# setting compatibility mode via CMD

Tags: windows-10, cmd.exe

I have the following folder structure for one of my tools:

- Original
- Scripts

In my scripts folder I have a .bat-script which runs a .exe-file in my Original-folder. This .exe requires a few compatibility modes like:

- run with Windows 98
- run at 640x480
- run 265bit mode
- disable fullscreen optimizations

Therefore my question is - how do you set all these compatibility options with in a script when you not know the whole path (just that you have to go one directory up and into the specified path) ?

Thank you for your help Greetings

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/379375/how-can-i-set-the-compatibility-mode-for-an-executable-from-the-command-line

Comment: I've tried it and the command line says it was successful but when i check, nothing was set.
Edit: This may be due to the fact, that i don't have the full path (since I want to have it more dynamic).

Comment: Forget what I was saying, figured it out. Thank you

Comment: If you have figured it out, please consider submitting a separate answer to help other, future readers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've figured it out how to do so. In case somebody wants to do the same here's how it goes:

```
REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers" /v \""C:\Path\to\exe.exe\" /t REG_SZ /d "WIN95" /f
```

If you want to add more than one attribute you have to change the part after /d, for example:

`/d "WINXPSP3 256COLOR 640X480"`

And last but not least if you want to do it from the directory you're currently into you change the path according to this:

`/v "%CD%\exe.exe"`

- Other compatibility options:

[image]

Comment: I run the reg command but when I check the file I don't see that the compatibility was updated, Any ideas ? ( I run it on Win Server 2012 )